# docker compose ckan container exits with error

Tags: ckan

I would like to do a POC on ckan ( data catalog service ). For that, I took the release branch of ckan ( 2.8.3 ) and followed the steps given here https://docs.ckan.org/en/2.8/maintaining/installing/install-from-docker-compose.html.

Wanted to use docker for the POC
My 'ckan' docker exits after running my docker compose file with the error
"ckan.plugins.core.PluginNotFoundException: recline_viewm"

Not sure where the plugin file is defined, it says recline_viewm.

Can someone please help me in solving this?

Comment: in the docker-compose at what step is the production.ini copied. I guess that is the culprit

Comment: Default preview plugin for ckan is recline_view. I think you have typo inside development.ini file. Please check that

Comment: Yes you are right. I am still figuring out at what step is the production.ini is created in the DockerFile of ckan ?

Comment: Can you send an example of Docker files ?